CFS thredds data don't work in xarray lib
I need to get u,v at 10 meters from CFS thredds from the historic forecast, but, when I open and try to get the variables, the error: FunctionalityNotEnabledError: Functionality not enabled pops.
My code:
arquivos = glob.glob('DataSet/CFS bruto/2012/Mar/*.grb2')
df_concat = xr.open_mfdataset(arquivos, engine='cfgrib',concat_dim=  ['valid_time'],combine='nested',filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'heightAboveGround','level':10})
df_concat['u10'].values

FunctionalityNotEnabledError              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 17
 14 latitude = pontos['lat'].values
 15 longitude= pontos['lon'].values

---> 17 df_concat['u10'].values
File c:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataarray.py:770, in       DataArray.values(self)
761 @property
762 def values(self) -> np.ndarray:
763     """
764     The array's data as a numpy.ndarray.
765 

(...)
768     type does not support coercion like this (e.g. cupy).
769     """
--> 770     return self.variable.values
File c:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py:508, in       Variable.values(self)
505 @property
506 def values(self):
507     """The variable's data as a numpy.ndarray"""

--> 508     return _as_array_or_item(self._data)
File c:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py:306, in   _as_array_or_item(data)

...
379     Raise the GribInternalError corresponding to errid.
380     """
--> 381     raise ERROR_MAPerrid
 FunctionalityNotEnabledError: Functionality not enabled

I try every method, but the same errors appear.
